# JDBC driver and Driver

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm preparing for Oracle Certified Java Proffesiona (OCP) certification. This is the first time I have come across  JDBC. In the book which I am preparing for certification (Kathy Sierra is one of authors), it is mentioned as:

> "The
>   collection of the implementation classes is called the JDBC driver. A JDBC
>   driver (lowercase “d“) is the collection of classes required to support the API, whereas Driver (uppercase “D“) is one of the implementations required in a
>   driver."

What is the author trying to mention about the Driver? Is Driver a class and is it a mandate to implement Driver in JDBC driver?

Comment: Just try to connect to a database using a JDBC library. The documenation of the library will tell you how this is done and you will see the name of a single class which the Driver (capital D) included in the library.

Comment: Yes, `java.sql.Driver` is a class (an interface actually) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) is a base interface for JDBC driver

> The interface that every driver class must implement.

For example for [OracleDriver](https://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)

> Implemented Interfaces:
> java.sql.Driver